# selecionar múltiplos inputs com jquery através do atributo 'name'

Tags: jquery

Tenho um script jquery que seleciona um determinado Select através do atributo 'name' e faz algumas alterações na label de um outro select:

`var selectRecheioGroup = $('select[name=recheio1] .grupoRecheio');`

A pergunta é: como eu posso fazer para que esta seleção possa abranger também outros 2 selects de nomes 'recheio2' e 'recheio3'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com jQuery, você pode utilizar todos [esses](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) selectores. Para o seu caso, o mais prático é o `^`. Ter `$("[title^='Tom']")` seleciona todos os elementos que possuem o atributo iniciado por `Tom`. Veja abaixo como seria para o seu exemplo, onde aplico um `padding` de 20 para os três elementos.

```js
$(function () {
  $("select[name^=recheio].grupoRecheio").css("padding", 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="recheio1" class="grupoRecheio">
  <option>Recheio 1</option>
</select>

<select name="recheio2" class="grupoRecheio">
  <option>Recheio 2</option>
</select>

<select name="recheio3" class="grupoRecheio">
  <option>Recheio 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No meu caso aqui funcionou muito bem, Anderson, obrigado! Agora, no caso de os outros 'names' não serem semelhantes, que outra alternativa eu teria?

Comment: Explique melhor "names não semelhantes".

Comment: Por exemplo, na solução que você deu, todos os 'names' possuem a combinação 'recheio' na composição do nome: recheio1, recheio2, recheio3. E se fossem, por exemplo, 'recheio1', 'decoracao' e 'chocolates'?

Comment: Aí só no braço mesmo, selecionando cada um individualmente.

Comment: Entendi. Pensei que houvesse alguma solução colocando uma vírgula tipo `var selectRecheioGroup = $('select[name=recheio1], [name=recheio2], [name=recheio3] .grupoRecheio');`